# Objective-C read outlook file

Tags: objective-c, outlook

I would like to write a program on Objective-C to read Outlook .pst files. Is there any MAPI provider or OLEDB connection strings that I can use with Objective-C on OSX?

Comment: Your best bet is google and see if some combination of keywords will come up with a usable implementation or, at the least, a clue to an implementation.

Comment: That's what I was looking for in StackOverflow

Comment: Yah... it is an esoteric enough question, that it is likely no one here has an off the cuff answer.  Thus, you are likely in the "do it yourself" mode.

Comment: Thanks bbum, I found that it is very esoteric so far ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MAPI Provider on OSX - Not that I'm aware of

OLEDB connection on OSX - Not that I'm aware of

(If either of these things existed, I'd most likely be aware of them)

Your best bet is to use [pstsdk](http://pstsdk.codeplex.com) (official Microsoft project) or [fairport](http://github.com/terrymah/Fairport) (my fork since leaving Microsoft) to read the files. They're cross platform header only libraries to read PST files.

Comment: Awesome Terry! This is a nice Christmas gift!